# Java JNI crash on NewObject. Other calls are working.

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Granted the code is not identical to others, it is very similar and unable to get past the NewObject call. There are a few other calls being executed which I would have expected to have failed before the NewObject call.

Here is my Stuff object which is used to create the Array.

```
public class Stuff implements java.io.Serializable, Cloneable
{
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public Stuff() {  }

    public Stuff(String s1, String s2)
    {
                this.field1 = s1;
        this.field2 = s2;
    }

    public String getField1() { return field1;   }
        public String getField2() { return field2;   }

    public void setField1(String s1) { this.field1 = s1;   }
        public void setField2(String s2) { this.field2 = s2;   }
}
```

The JavaJNITest.java code is very minimal .

```
public class JavaJNITest
{
   static
   {
      System.loadLibrary("myLib");
   }

   private native Stuff[] getStuffArray();

   // Test Driver
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new JavaJNITest().getStuffArray();
   }
}
```

Here is the cCodeForLIbrary.c file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "JavaJNITest.h"


typedef struct javaStuff_st
{
    jclass      class;
    jmethodID   constructor;
    jfieldID    field1;   /*jstring*/
    jfieldID    field2;  /*jstring*/
  }javaStuff;

  javaStuff    javaStuff_s;

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_JavaJNITest_getStuffArray (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
        jobjectArray    retVal=NULL;
    jobject         obj1;
        jclass                  javaStuffClass;

    printf("Inside JNI LIbrary\n");

    printf("Finding class\n");

        javaStuffClass=(*env)->FindClass(env, "Stuff");
        if (javaStuffClass == NULL)
                printf("Class NOT found\n");
        else
                printf("Class FOUND \n");

    printf("Creating Global Ref\n");
        javaStuff_s.class=(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, javaStuffClass);

    printf("Creating JavaObjectArray\n");

        retVal=(*env)->NewObjectArray(env,
                                (jsize)10,
                            javaStuff_s.class,  NULL);

    if (retVal == NULL)
        printf("Array NOT created\n");
    else
        printf("Array CREATED \n");

    printf("Creating single Object\n" );
        obj1 =(*env)->NewObject(env,
                                javaStuff_s.class,
                                javaStuff_s.constructor);

    if (obj1 == NULL)
        printf("Object NOT created\n");
    else
        printf("Object CREATED \n");

    printf("Done!!!\n");
        return retVal;
}
```

Here are the build commands :

```
rm -f *.class *.so *.o
javac Stuff.java
javac JavaJNITest.java
javac -h . JavaJNITest.java

gcc -fPIC -shared  -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux cCodeForLIbrary.c -o libmyLib.so
```

When executed, here is the output :

```
> java -classpath . -Djava.library.path=. JavaJNITest
    Inside JNI LIbrary
    Finding class
    Class FOUND
    Creating Global Ref
    Creating JavaObjectArray
    Array CREATED
    Creating single Object
```

It crashes on the "NewObject" yet the "NewObjectArray" is successful.

The code isn't really much different than other, but there is obviously something that is causing this to fail. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see you calling `GetMethodID` anywhere to obtain the `jmethodID` of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. It works after adding the call. Most samples I read didn't make this call but they also weren't calling NewObject. I assumed it was only needed it calling a constructor which is different from the default.